# How do I programmatically delete an order?

Tags: 8, commerce

My head is about to pop. I'm trying to figure out how to delete commerce orders programmatically. I created a rest export with the order IDs I want to delete. I've parsed that and put the IDs into an array. Now I want to loop through that array and delete the orders.

json parsing, and retrieving order_id work fine.

I'm so close but I can't figure out how to properly reference commerce_order_delete or commerce_cart_commerce_order_delete?

```
function afc_custom_node_view(array &$build, \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {
          if ($entity->id() == 803) {
            $url = 'my url';
            $jsonString = file_get_contents($url);
            $jsonDecoded = json_decode($jsonString, true);
            $object = new stdClass();
            foreach($jsonDecoded as $row){
            if ($row['order_id'] == 121) {
                $object->order_id = $row['order_id'];
                // $order = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_order')->load($row['order_id']);
                commerce_cart_commerce_order_delete($object);
            }

            }
          }
    }
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to commerce_cart_commerce_order_delete() must be an instance of Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderInterface, instance of stdClass given,
```

**UPDATE #2**
**New Code**

```
use Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderInterface;

  if ($entity->id() == 803) {
    $url = 'https://myurl.com/pull-ghosts';
    $jsonString = file_get_contents($url);
    $jsonDecoded = json_decode($jsonString, true);

    $object = new OrderInterface;

    foreach($jsonDecoded as $row){
      if ($row['order_id'] == 121) {
        $object->setOrderNumber($row['order_id']);
        commerce_cart_commerce_order_delete($object);
        print 'deleted';
      }
    }
  }
```

**SAME ERROR:**

```
error: Cannot instantiate interface Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderInterface in afc_custom_node_view()
```

Comment: There is no such thing as commerce_order_delete(). commerce_cart_commerce_order_delete() is a hook implementation and should never be invoked manually.

Commerce entities are deleted like any other Drupal entity. $order->delete(); or $order_storage->delete([$order]);

Comment: Also, you don't use `new` with a PHP interface. `new OrderInterface` is going to give you an error message.

Comment: You have the order id, so why not load the order object with that?
Something like Order::load($id); Actually dunno the base class of the Interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading it like a normal entity did the trick.

**How to load and delete commerce order programmatically**

```
$ord_id=121;
$order = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_order')->load($ord_id);
$order->delete();
```

Here is the entire snippet on my ultimate goal which was deleting abandoned orders in the cart.
**How to remove commerce orders automatically**

**How to delete ghost commerce registrations in cart**

**Custom cron to delete commerce orders programmatically**

**Load a view programmatically loop through values and delete orders**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_cron().
 */
 function my_module_cron() {
   //load a view showing orders still in cart
   $view = \Drupal\views\Views::getView('commerce_carts');
   //the name of your display, i chose a simple rest display with the order_id field
   $view->setDisplay('rest_export_1');
   $view->execute();

   foreach($view->result as $row){
     //load the order
     $order = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_order')->load($row->order_id);
     $oid = $order->id();
     //delete the order
     $order->delete();
     //log to dblog
     \Drupal::logger('afc_commerce_registration')->notice('Clearing ghost registration, deleted: @oid.',
       array(
           '@oid' => $oid,
       ));
   }
 }
```

You can add the Created date field to the view, and test time values before deleting. In my case, it doesn't matter.

Thanks for the help everyone

Answer (score 1):

For one, in your updated code, you cannot instantiate an Interface in PHP. This is throwing the error. If you were to need a new instance, you would instead use the `Order` class which implements the `OrderInterface` Interface.

As Orders are Entities, you *should* be able to simply load the Order and delete it.

Example:

```
use Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\Order;

$my_order = Order::load(122); // Or, your Order ID
$my_order->delete();
```

This should delete the Entity, which is your Order in this case.

Answer (score -2):

You need your object to be of the class [`Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderInterface`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce/tree/modules/order/src/Entity/OrderInterface.php?id=83e6660a24d846bfe56e55de4a111f3f2c2a3556) instead of an empty class.

Use this instead: (**Update**)

```
use Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderInterface;

$object = new OrderInterface;

foreach($jsonDecoded as $row){
  if ($row['order_id'] == 121) {
    $object->setOrderNumber($row['order_id']);
    commerce_cart_commerce_order_delete($object);
    print 'deleted';
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems like exactly the right path, but getting an error. Update on original post: error: Cannot instantiate interface Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderInterface in afc_custom_node_view()

Comment: Same Error: Cannot instantiate interface Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderInterface in